# MongoDB insertMany() working fine and data is saving to the Database, but gives 400 Bad request error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

**This is my node JS**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Posts = require("../../models/vendorProjectsDatabaseExcellUpload");

router.post('/vendorProjectsDatabasesExcell/save',(req,res) => {

  const newPost = req.body;
  // console.log(newPost);

  // Posts.insertMany(newPost).then((err) =>{
  //   if(err){
  //     return res.status(400).json({
  //       error:err
  //     });
  //   }
  //   return res.status(200).json({
  //     success:"Project Details Added Successfully"
  //   });
  // });


    try {
      const options = { ordered: true };
      const result = Posts.insertMany(newPost, options).then((err) =>{
        if(err){
          return res.status(400).json({
            error:err
          });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          success:"Project Details Added Successfully"
        });
      });
      
      console.log(`All documents were inserted`);
    } finally {
      console.log('done');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is my React.js**

```
    const uplaodHandler = async (e) => {
    // const uplaodHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newPost = items;
    // console.log(newPost);

    await axios
      .post('http://localhost:8072/vendorProjectsDatabasesExcell/save', newPost)
      .then((result) => {
        alert(result);
        alert('New Project Added now');
        // navigate('/dashboard/DatabasesUploadProjectFilesVendorProjects', { replace: true });
        console.log(newPost);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // console.log(error.response.data);
        // console.log(error.response.status);
        // console.log(error.response.headers);
      });
  };
```

Other post and put request in other pages of the same app is works fine without any error.

In here also the json data array post to the mongo DB without any issue. Only problem is it is giving the bad request 400 error.

Comment: You are returning 400 from a successful response, the then func is for success, use catch func for failure and send 400 there

Comment: @Osmanys Please can you elaborate more. Im newbie in this field.

Comment: Please help me I worked on this for days ;(

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this part:

```js
const result = Posts.insertMany(newPost, options)
.then((res) =>{
     return json({success:"Project Details Added Successfully"});
}).catch((err) => {
    return json({error:err});
});
```

Comment: Bro still comes the same error.                                                                                POST http://localhost:8072/vendorProjectsDatabasesExcell/save 400 (Bad Request)
UploadExcellData.js:80 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)

Comment: UploadExcellData... you are trying to upload a file??

Comment: No it is Uploading JSON array. Excell data is converted to Json array and then json array is inserted to mongoDB with insert many. All the data goes to the DB with no issue. Only problem is it is giving this 400 bad request error.

Comment: You're overwriting `res` in the `.then()`